# TFS 2018 - Fields cleaning

Tags: service, tfs, visual-studio-extensions

Is it possible to clean the fields when the user saves the changes?

Comment in detail: I have a monitoring service that calculates the values of the history of a work item (only task), based on it applies logic to autocalculate them.
When the user enters a work item, I need those fields to be empty, but that the previously loaded value can be displayed in the history.

Comment: You can with webhook or server-side plugin manipulate the work item after each save

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your solution is valid, but ... the change would not be instantly, that is, if the user completes the values and saves the changes, it should be cleaned instantly so that it can be completed again.